# Switch vertical carousel (desktop) to horizontal carousel in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, transform, carousel, slick.js

They know a one plugin that let me change/transform a vertical (desktop view) carousel to a horizontal carousel on mobile devices?

Now I'm working with slick plugin but I can't get the result that I need, this is my JS code:

```
          $('.demo-slider).slick({
                      vertical: true;
                    });
           var windowWidth = $(window).width();
              if(windowWidth < 768){
                  $('.demo-slider').slick('unslick',function(){
                   $('.demo-slider).slick({
                      vertical: false;
                    });
                });
           }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think where you are going wrong is you're initializing `slick()` twice (you also forgot closing `'` on your jQuery selectors). I would switch the faux media query to be out of `slick()`'s initialization, like this:

```
// 1- Get window width 
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

// 2- For all devices under or at 768px, use horizontal orientation
if(windowWidth <= 768) {
  $('.demo-slider').slick({
    vertical: false,
  });
} 
// 3- For all devices over 768px, use vertical orientation
else {
  $('.demo-slider').slick({
    vertical: true,
  });
}
```

*note, I've never used slickslider, just looking at your JS.

Comment: instead `vertical: true;` must be `vertical: true,`

Comment: This is a poor answer, don't use this answer, [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52813364/3367974) answer is the correct solution.

Answer (score 7):

```
$('.demo-slider').slick({   
vertical: true,
responsive: [               
{
    breakpoint: 767,
    settings: {
    vertical: false
    }
}]
});
```

Slick have own responsive breakpoints. This will be work much better